# How to remove margin area in progress bar Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use [Bootstrap 4 Progress component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/progress/). I need it to be between words in a sentence. As it is designed to cover the whole row, I'm trying to make it a smaller block so that I can put it between words. I minimized the size changing its width, but for some reason, it still has margin, but the developer tool shows there is no any margin.

I don't know how I can handle the margin thing. Is there anything hidden configuration from Bootstrap 4?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird. I didn't see the margins you mentioned on my developer tool.

Anyway, if you want the progress bar to be between words, you can set its `display: inline-block;`. Optionally you can assign a width to it as well:

```
span.progress {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 12rem;    /* optional */
}
```

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/255749/

[image]